# See all not merged revisions in Intellij-SVN

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, merge

Is it possible to see all revision that weren't merged directly in IntelliJ with the SVN integration ? This would be handy while merging one branch into another in order to keep track of all not merged revisions from the said branch.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special view that will show you unmerged revisions, however, while merging you could use the **Select With Pre-filter** option that will list not merged revisions.